# Common pattern of keyboard shortcuts on websites

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

For instance what could activate a search field?

- Sometimes it's `S`
- othertimes `F`
- or `esc`
- in gmail it's `/`

Feels like it's a wild west out there in the keyboard shortcut universe. A standard would be something, just thinking...

Is it cause hotkeys are rather new thing in the interwebs? Or the fact that every site has so unique needs?

Do you have a pattern you use?